# While loop issues with arduino robot

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am creating code to operate a robot. It is supposed to tell the robot when to turn depending of the reading it gets from its sensors. I tried an if statement for the turning it, and was not happy with how the robot turned. I felt a while loop was better as it would not have to go through the entire code to keep checking if it should continue to turn, and would stay in the while loop until the turn is complete. The issue I am having is that the code does not pull readings from the sensors and goes directly into the while loop and stays there. How can I resolve this issue?

```
>#include<SoftwareSerial.h> // Import the serial Library
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_MS_PWMServoDriver.h"

// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield();
// Select which 'port' M1, M2, M3 or M4. In this case, M1

Adafruit_DCMotor *FL= AFMS.getMotor(1); //Front left motor

Adafruit_DCMotor *FR= AFMS.getMotor(4); //Front right motor


int left_trig = 8;
int left_echo = 9;

int mid_trig = 5;
int mid_echo = 6;

int right_trig = 3;
int right_echo = 4;
long duration1, duration2, duration3, inches1, inches2, inches3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
AFMS.begin();  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz

  //This establishes the sensors as inputs and outputs
 pinMode(left_trig,OUTPUT);   
  pinMode(left_echo,INPUT);

  pinMode (mid_trig,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mid_echo,INPUT);

  pinMode (right_trig,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right_echo,INPUT);

  FL->setSpeed(150);
  FL->run(FORWARD);
  //FL->run(RELEASE);
  FR->setSpeed(150);
  FR->run(BACKWARD);
  //FR->run(RELEASE);
}

void loop() {

   digitalWrite(left_trig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(left_trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
   duration1 = pulseIn(left_echo,HIGH);


 // pinMode (mid_trig,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(mid_trig, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(mid_trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
     duration2 = pulseIn(mid_echo, HIGH);

//  pinMode (right_trig,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(right_trig, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(right_trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
   duration3 = pulseIn(right_echo, HIGH);

    // convert the time into inches
  inches1 = microsecondsToInches(duration1);
  inches2 = microsecondsToInches(duration2);
  inches3 = microsecondsToInches(duration3);

   FL->setSpeed(150);
  FL->run(FORWARD);
  FR->setSpeed(150);
  FR->run(BACKWARD);

Serial.print(inches1);
  Serial.print("in,\t");
    Serial.print(inches2);
  Serial.print("in,\t");
    Serial.print(inches3);
  Serial.print("in");
  Serial.println();

while(inches3 <=8 && inches2 <=12){
//  Serial.print(inches1);
//  Serial.print("win,\t");
//    Serial.print(inches2);
//  Serial.print("win,\t");
//    Serial.print(inches3);
//  Serial.print("win");
//  Serial.println();
  FL->setSpeed(120);
  FL->run(BACKWARD);
  FR->setSpeed(120);
  FR->run(BACKWARD);

}

 FL->setSpeed(150);
  FL->run(FORWARD);
  FR->setSpeed(150);
  FR->run(BACKWARD);

delay(50);
}
long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing inside your while loop will ever change the values of inches3 or inches2.  If they are less than 8 and 12 respectively to get you into the while loop then they'll still be that every time it comes back around to check.  So this is an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion after I looked back over it and that was the issue. the turning still isn't smooth. I am afraid it may be the motors I am using, but I am hoping it is the code as that would be an easier fix. Looking over it, do see any areas that could be better improved upon?

Answer (score 0):

Being that the value is never updated in the while loop, you should be able to add the code that checks the sensors inside your while loop like this:

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h> // Import the serial Library
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_MS_PWMServoDriver.h"

// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield();
// Select which 'port' M1, M2, M3 or M4. In this case, M1

Adafruit_DCMotor *FL= AFMS.getMotor(1); //Front left motor

Adafruit_DCMotor *FR= AFMS.getMotor(4); //Front right motor


int left_trig = 8;
int left_echo = 9;

int mid_trig = 5;
int mid_echo = 6;

int right_trig = 3;
int right_echo = 4;
long duration1, duration2, duration3, inches1, inches2, inches3;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    AFMS.begin();  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz

    //This establishes the sensors as inputs and outputs
    pinMode(left_trig,OUTPUT);   
    pinMode(left_echo,INPUT);

    pinMode (mid_trig,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(mid_echo,INPUT);

    pinMode (right_trig,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(right_echo,INPUT);

    FL->setSpeed(150);
    FL->run(FORWARD);
    //FL->run(RELEASE);
    FR->setSpeed(150);
    FR->run(BACKWARD);
    //FR->run(RELEASE);
}

void loop() 
{

    digitalWrite(left_trig, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2); 
    digitalWrite(left_trig, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); 
    duration1 = pulseIn(left_echo,HIGH);


    // pinMode (mid_trig,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(mid_trig, LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(2); 
    digitalWrite(mid_trig, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    duration2 = pulseIn(mid_echo, HIGH);

    //  pinMode (right_trig,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(right_trig, LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(2); 
    digitalWrite(right_trig, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    duration3 = pulseIn(right_echo, HIGH);

    // convert the time into inches
    inches1 = microsecondsToInches(duration1);
    inches2 = microsecondsToInches(duration2);
    inches3 = microsecondsToInches(duration3);

    FL->setSpeed(150);
    FL->run(FORWARD);
    FR->setSpeed(150);
    FR->run(BACKWARD);

    Serial.print(inches1);
    Serial.print("in,\t");
    Serial.print(inches2);
    Serial.print("in,\t");
    Serial.print(inches3);
    Serial.print("in");
    Serial.println();

    while(inches3 <=8 && inches2 <=12)
    {

        // convert the time into inches
        inches1 = microsecondsToInches(duration1);
        inches2 = microsecondsToInches(duration2);
        inches3 = microsecondsToInches(duration3);

        //  Serial.print(inches1);
        //  Serial.print("win,\t");
        //    Serial.print(inches2);
        //  Serial.print("win,\t");
        //    Serial.print(inches3);
        //  Serial.print("win");
        //  Serial.println();
        FL->setSpeed(120);
        FL->run(BACKWARD);
        FR->setSpeed(120);
        FR->run(BACKWARD);
    }

    FL->setSpeed(150);
    FL->run(FORWARD);
    FR->setSpeed(150);
    FR->run(BACKWARD);

    delay(50);
}
long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) 
{
    return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}
```